# How to get back the original implementation of input[time]

Tags: angularjs

Angular JS (1.x) has a directive for input[time].

I think to map time to a datetime causes more new problems than solving some (when mapping time to a standard javascript time I think to map to number of seconds or milliseconds would be a much better approach)

I want get back to the original html5 implementation. Is there a way to do so?

The original implementation does/should not use Date! See
https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html

Comment: What do you mean by _"get back"_? It's not gone. Moreover you can get the number milliseconds from the `Date` object.

Comment: How can I access the original input[time] which does not use Date?

Comment: The "original implementation" can be accessed  with `element` argument of the link function.